# Good container for insert-in-order? C++

Tags: c++, path-finding

Hi I was wondering what the best container for inserting elements in order in? A map I think is unnecessary since I am just going to be accessing the element at the front, popping it and then inserting more elements (I'm implementing a pathfinding algorithm (Dijkstra) with weights)

I could probably have used a list and inserted in order myself, but the inability to bisect (because you start accessing at the front or back) would be hindering to performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only access the front and back, [`std::deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/) (double-ended queue) fits the bill perfectly.

However, for a Dijkstra algorithm, don't you need a priority queue instead?

Comment: I'm inserting random elements which need to go in in order too.
I need to specify a container type for priority queue, what should I use for that?

Comment: Oh, you meant that you want the queue to be sorted according to some criterion; I read it as "insertion order". In that case, how about [`std::priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/)? :)

Comment: Kk but it says it can only use vectors or queues as the internal container :/

Comment: @Alasdair: It can use a `std::vector` or `std::deque` as the underlying container. Does that matter though? If you are using the `std::priority_queue` member functions you won't be accessing the underlying container directly.

Comment: Nah I was just concerned about efficiency, thinking about it though a sequential access container does make sense so it can be bisected efficiently, its just the primary operation is going to be insert in order.

Comment: @Alasdair: For a Dijkstra, you don't need the entire list to be sorted. You just need an efficient way to extract the smallest element, which is exactly what a PQ (here based on a min-heap) provides.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++ there is a `std::priority_queue` container adapter in the `<queue>` header file.